# How to get array in ajax response to another field

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have an array like

```
[{"id_pelanggan":"1","id_tipe":"5","nama_pelanggan":"ASD","alamat_jalan":"DS","alamat_kota":"1","alamat_provinsi":"ATA","kontak_pelanggan":"45454"}]
```

and my ajax

```
$(function() {
  $("#autocomplete").change(function(){
    var namaagen = $("#autocomplete").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo site_url('Pelanggan/tampil_where'); ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'namaagen': namaagen
      },
      success: function (agen) {
        $("#napem").val(agen['nama_pelanggan']);
      }
    });
  });
});
  });
});
```

controller :

```
public function tampil_where(){  
$nama = $this->input->post('namaagen');
$query = $this->pelanggan_m->tampilwhere($nama);
echo json_encode($query);}
```

models:

```
public function tampilwhere($nama){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('nm_pelanggan');
$this->db->where('nama_pelanggan',$nama);
$this->db->order_by('id_pelanggan', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $query;
}
```

but nothing happen and i already add `alert(agen['nama_pelanggan']);` in response success and show alert undefined pls help , thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please change your alert code, right now you don't access response array in the proper way:-**

```
alert(agen[0]['nama_pelanggan']);
```

**Instead of:-**

```
alert(agen['nama_pelanggan']);
```

Thanks

Comment: wow thank you very much for you help bro that solved my prob -A-

Comment: @NewbsWantGeeks Or make any loop for agen array and call append or whatever. Next time you should check console because it must throw any error.

Comment: Good to hear that, Thank you NewbsWantGeeks